# process.env in react front file are working, but... [strange]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a process.env implementation that works very well, until today.
When I use it in a particular function, it doesn't work. However, in the parent function, it works.

My webpack.config is like this :

```
  const env = dotenv.config().parsed;
  // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
  const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});
  return {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(
          path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)),
          "public/index.html"
        ),
        filename: "index.html",
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
    ],
    .....
}
```

And, in my custom fetch hook :

```
  async function fetchData(apiPath, formData = null, method = null) {
    method =
      formData === null && method === null
        ? "get"
        : formData !== null
        ? "post"
        : method;

    if (!apiPath) return;
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      let xsrfToken = localStorage.getItem("xsrfToken");
      if (xsrfToken !== "undefined") {
        xsrfToken = JSON.parse(xsrfToken);
      } else {
        xsrfToken = null;
      }

      const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL + apiPath, { // process.env works here
        method: method,
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "x-xsrf-token": xsrfToken,
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: formData,
      });
      const fetchResponse = await response.json();
      if (auth.accessToken) {
        // If logged in, check token
        console.log(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN); // still works

        let decodedToken = jwtDecode(
          fetchResponse.accessToken,
          process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN, // process is not defined
          {
            algorithms: process.env.ALGORYTHM,
          }
        );
      }
```

I clearly can workaround, but with every problem, I want to understand, so if the community knows what's wrong, I'd be happy to learn something new.
Thanks in advance

EDIT : error came from console, I get ReferenceError: process is not defined at fetchData (useFetch.js:49:23) and the custom hook function stop here

Comment: How do you know `process` is not defined? Do you get an error message? What is the exact error message?

Comment: in console, I get ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at fetchData (useFetch.js:49:23)
and the fetch function stop here

Comment: Could be a bug. I would try to create a [mcve] and analyze the problem.

Comment: If I read the source page of the error, I can see : 
       let decodedToken = (0,jwt_decode__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])(fetchResponse.accessToken, "ZoPmqAbHUY17eL6Q5M9Aiofgeo85P9",
        // process is not defined
        {
          algorithms: "HS256"
        });
So, the process.env variables are rightly readed, the problem is coming from the imported module and webpack I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at this line :

```
algorithms: process.env.ALGORYTHM,
```

The real entity was process.env.ALGORITHM.....

What I learn today is that inside some npm module function, the error is not explicit as JS do naturally (process.env.ALOGYTHM is not defined would have been perfect). And the line of the error was... erroned !

Thanks to jabaa, (sorry)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).